# Shortest network to connect multiple points (Euclidean Steiner Tree problem)

Tags: qgis, network, shortest-path

I have a shapefile (Houses.shp) with points representing houses in a village (from 10 to 40 houses per village). I want to connect the houses in each village to each other with the shortest possible network layout. I have been using so far a plug-in (ReconstructLine) which gives me the Minimum Spanning Tree, with the constraint that each node of the network has to correspond to one of the houses. What I am looking for is a way to create the Euclidean Steiner Tree, which leaves the possibility of creating new nodes laying in between different houses if the resulting network is shorter (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Euclidean_Steiner_tree for detailed explanation). 
I checked various GRASS tools such as v.net.steiner but that's not what I am looking for because it only works for shortest paths between nodes along a pre-existing network.

I know that the Euclidean Steiner Tree problem for N elements is an NP-hard problem, but I was wondering if there is any approximation that could work for a limited number of houses like in my case, through python coding (of which I have very little experience) or with an existing tool.

Comment: You can try this as it solves a similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/361193/63861