# Running v.net.steiner in segments?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, network

I am using GRASS GIS 7.6 on a CentOS server with 157 GB of RAM. The vector categories of the network layer that I need to run the Steiner tree algorithm on are as follows:

```
Layer/table: 1/network
type       count        min        max
point          0          0          0
line      364591          1     364591
boundary       0          0          0
centroid       0          0          0
area           0          0          0
face           0          0          0
kernel         0          0          0
all       364591          1     364591
Layer: 2
type       count        min        max
point       2174          1       2176
line           0          0          0
boundary       0          0          0
centroid       0          0          0
area           0          0          0
face           0          0          0
kernel         0          0          0
all         2174          1       2176
```

However even the 157 GB of RAM isn't sufficient and the process gets killed as follows:

```
GRASS 7.6.0 (srilanka):/home/asel/tmp/rds > v.net.steiner network arc_layer=1 node_layer=2 terminal_cats=0-2176 out=mysteinerSL
Number of terminals: 2172
Number of Steiner points set to 2170
Killed
```

I understand that this is due to the fact that the Steiner tree algorithm, at least at present, isn't very memory efficient. So I was wondering if I were to divide my network into segments and run v.net.steiner on each of them individually if I'd still get the desired output.

Comment: I'm working on it but I'm facing this error using v.net.steiner: Number of terminals: 0
ERROR: Terminales insuficientes (<2)

Comment: I think you could check this answer, may be this R process works for you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/361193/63861