# Steiner Tree optimization

Tags: python, networkx

I have a NetworkX graph corresponding to a mix of road and telecommunication network of a town, and different sets of nodes (of variable size) representing the location of network devices. I have to find an optimal path connecting all devices along the network and I tought the `steiner_tree` algorithmn available in NetworkX should do the trick.

Most of the time I get results within a reasonable time and with a reasonable use of resources (i.e. RAM). Sometimes however, when working with graph of few thousands nodes (around 5000) the process takes longer and eats a great amount of RAM.

I am searching for ways to reduce the complexity of the graph and I found the `contracted_nodes` function in `networkx.algorithms.minors` module. I use it to "contract" any node with a degree of 2, obtaining a single edge out of a sequence of consecutive edges.

The `contracted_nodes` has an optional `self_loop` parameter with the effect of preserving contracted edges as self loops.

Which can be the effects, if any, of these self loops on the `steiner_tree` algorithm?

Comment: If you want to try a different approach, try this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/361193/63861

Answer (score 1):

You can contract all nodes of degree 2 except for the terminals (the nodes that should always be in your tree). The reason is that you will never have a non-terminal node as a leaf in an optimal Steiner tree, otherwise you could just remove it from the tree. You don't need the self loops.
As a side note: the Steiner tree algorithm in networkxx is not only quite slow, but also does not provide optimal solutions.
You can get much faster and better results with
https://scipjack.zib.de/

Comment: Plaese read @whuber's answer in "[Promoting something I am associated with?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733/29431)".

Comment: Sinne I use my real name here, I don't think I am hiding any association. My main interest is for people to use Steiner trees succesfully in practice, the code is open source